# I want to have a cell to store different values for different months in excel (same cell but 12 values for 12 months)

Tags: excel

Is it possible to have a cell which contains a different value for each month? the value will be entered manually for each month(for example for Jan its 2, for Feb its 5 and.... in the same cell)  and I will scroll from one month to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VLOOKUP`, but you will need a data array for the values.
The Formula for D2 is `=VLOOKUP(D1,A1:B12,2,FALSE)`. Your manually entered value goes into D1.

[image]